# How to fire a do_action on reloading the WP customizer?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to clear the cache of a plugin on reloading the preview of the WordPress customizer because I can only see the changes I make if the cache is refreshed. I can do this manually, but my goal is to do it also when the WP customizer refreshes.

I have come this far:

```
function px_clear_bb_cache() {
FLBuilderModel::delete_asset_cache_for_all_posts();
}
do_action( 'customize_save', 'px_clear_bb_cache' );
```

I'm running into the following problems:

1. After saving the customizer, I can only see the changes after closing the customizer. It would be great if the customizer reloads / refreshes on save.
2. **But even better** would be if the above php function would fire every time the customizer reloads / refreshed when a value is changed.

Maybe I need jQuery + AJAX to hook into the preview_init and fire this do_action? No idea how to do that.

Comment: I think your question is less programming related but more related to wordpress development as it is about quite some specific state handling within the wordpress application. You may want to consider https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ as a more fitting Q&A site.

Comment: Good suggestion, didn't know this existed. Going to post the question there and if I have the answer post it back here to complete my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `customize_save_after` hook.

```
do_action( 'customize_save_after', 'px_clear_bb_cache' );
```

Docs reference:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_save_after/

Comment: Tried that also, but running into the same problems:
1. Doesn't show results after saving, I think because it's reloaded with ajax. 
2. Doesn't show results on reloading preview.